# 22mm air/fuel sensor socket for Honda CR-V MK3

Tags: o2-sensor, socket

I am trying to find a socket to take out my air/fuel sensor but so far after having bought and tried several sockets, the sockets I tried all seem to be a bit too thick so just can't get all the way down through the hole.

Is there a socket somebody could recommend trying that might fit the one in the picture? [image]

Comment: I know it may not sound very professional, but if I was struggling to get a suitable tool, I would consider buying a cheap suitably long socket and use a grinder to thin the wall down so that it fits correctly.

Comment: That would entail me getting a grinder to start with :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest giving one of the below a try.  The first two I found on Amazon.  The Grey Pneumatic I found on Google using "thin wall socket 22mm" as my search criteria.

Sunex 2622 1/2-Inch Drive 22-Mm Extra Thin Wall Deep Impact Socket

Performance Tool W32926 1/2-Inch Impact Drive 22mm Thin Wall Socket, 1/2" Impact Drive 22mm

Grey Pneumatic 1/2" Drive x 22mm Extra-Thin Wall Deep

Comment: Thank you for the search criteria, I found one specialised for oxygen/lambda sensors using your suggestion: Laser 6672 Thin Walled Lambda Sensor Socket 1/2"D 22mm - for Ford